# Change SVG symbol size based on a field value range

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have been experimenting with QGIS for about three weeks now.

I am using a SVG symbol that I created and successfully loaded into the directory for **QGIS 3.10.**  I can make it appear on the map.

It represents the size of a colony and I would like the size to reflect the number of inhabitants, based on ranges of numbers.

I have created a layer to represent these colonies, with a field called "number"

What I want to do is have the size of the SVG symbol for each colony change based on the value in the field "number"

Ideally, I want to use ranges of numbers, so a colony between 1-10 inhabitants would be the smallest size symbol, 11-50 the next size and so on.

I have tried using the data defined override box, but clearly have no idea of correct syntax to either identify that I want the size to change based on a number range taken from the "Number" field or to specify that it is the symbol size I want to change.

If anyone can point me to an appropriate tutorial, I have been unsuccessful finding one on my own!

If you have a process that I am missing that would be great

If there is a way to do data defined, I would be interested in that too.

My programming background is an ancient use of OpenScript (Proprietary for the old Toolbook program) and a minuscule amount of whatever you use to make excel do tricks!

Comment: http://learngis.uk/proportional-symbol-map-qgis-2-18/

Comment: Beautiful - thank you.

Comment: For future reference, when one of your questions gets put on hold, you can get it re-opened if you fix whatever was wrong with it. (Use the [edit] link under your question to improve the original question instead of providing information in the comments section.) In the case of your first question, it was just that you didn't say what software you were using.

Comment: What is your question?  It does not have the single question mark in your question body that would make it obvious.

Comment: Polygeo - I asked people to direct me to an appropriate tutorial or tell me what I might be missing in my process.  But no, I did not use a question mark.  I assume then that requests for help must take the form of a question.  As a new user, I am finding the system rules here quite rigid.  I don't have the experience to speak the language you seem to want. The issue has been solved by someone who did understand the question, but I had to re-write it (and you edited that one too, as there seems to be a bias against any someone expressing concern that their question may not be clear?)